# Removing fade effect from border css

Tags: html, css

I've attempted to recreate a curved line using border-left. However, the top and bottom of the border seem to fade and I'm having trouble removing it.

What I'm trying to create

[image: Desired result]

My current result:

[image: current result]

My code so far:

```
.border {
border-left: 2px dashed #c6c6c6;
border-radius: 10%/200px;
}
```

```
<div class="border"></div>
```

How would I go about fixing this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always gonna look 'faded' until you add the rest of the border attributes for bottom, top, and right.

```
.border {
   min-height: 500px;
   min-width: 500px;

   border-left: 2px dashed #c6c6c6;
   border-right: 2px dashed #c6c6c6;
   border-bottom: 2px dashed #c6c6c6;
   border-top: 2px dashed #c6c6c6;

   border-radius: 10%/200px;
}
```

When you only specify one, the web browser has to determine when exactly to start and stop drawing the left border, and with a lot of curvature there's really no one obvious point for stopping, so it fades the border out gradually as a compromise :p